# How to fix differences in Font Rendering between Fedora (27/28) and CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, fedora, antialiasing, xserver, font-rendering

We are hosting a virtualized desktop for web stack developers on vmware. Currently, the developer box is based on Fedora (27/28), but I would like to move it to CentOS 7 since it's closer our Red Hat Prod Infrastructure.

We are using mostly identical Ansible scripts to set up the developer boxes for both Fedora and CentOS, use XFCE4 as desktop environment, and use the EPEL repository for some packages such as xrdp (so they are the same version in both setups).

The one huge noticeable difference between the two developer boxes is the font rendering. It looks nice on Fedora but bad on CentOS, even though the identical font/font-sizes and (where possible) anti-aliasing options are selected.

How can I get CentOS to have Font Rendering of similar quality as Fedora?

Comment: This is probably related to font settings in ``Xresources``, ``fonts.conf`` or ``gtkrc``. However, I think this question would be more fitting on superuser.com.

Comment: ok, opened the question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1345873/how-to-fix-differences-in-font-rendering-between-fedora-27-28-and-centos-7)